# Update automatic attributes in Opscode Chef (serialized_object)

Tags: json, postgresql, attributes, chef-infra

I had a couple of nodes in my chef server that had a problem while bootstrapping and missed the FQDN and domain automatic attributes due to which they were not indexed by SOLR and not searchable by knife. I could not rebootstrap these machines, but wanted to fix this and it took me a while to do so. Therefore I am posting this hoping that it will save others some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic attributes are stored by Chef in the database and are not editable by knife (see Chef Attributes Overview). They are stored in chef's database as a column named serialized_object in the nodes table in hex and is in fact a gzipped JSON string.

To obtain the JSON string:

- Use a PostgreSQL client to connect to the chef PostgreSQL (you can find the credentials on the chef server in /etc/chef-server/chef-server-secrets.json)
- Save the contents of the serialized_object to a file say serialized_object.hex (it should look something like '\x1f8b08000...')
- Run: xxd -p -r serialized_object.hex > serialized_object.gz
- Run: gunzip serialized_object.gz

Now the file serialized_object contains the attributes in JSON format which you can edit. After editing you can store its contents back in chef server by following this:

- Run: gzip serialized_object
- Run: xxd -p serialized_object.gz > serialized_object.hex
- Now you need to use the PostgreSQL client and insert the Hex data (be sure to remove prefix backslashes and x from the hex string) with the following query:

  update nodes set serialized_object = decode('1f8b08000...','hex') where name = ''

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: It's hilarious that they store it as gzipped JSON, given that PostgreSQL automatically compresses column values.